# How can we get a URL which is a parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get the URL which is a parameter but unfortunately i get a Forbidden error

Eg: http://project.com/http://google.com

If i put the above url, my parameter should be http://google.com but i am not getting that. I get a Forbidden Error.

The project i am working on is Codeigniter

Here is what i have done for routes

```
$route['(:any)'] = "mycontroller";
```

Comment: I think you may need url encode any slashes, colons, or periods, etc. in your 'parameter'.

Comment: What if its user input on the URL itself.

Comment: Split string after third slash using javascript on input form, then url encode second half.

Answer (score 2):

You should encode your parameters before using it on GET.

```
echo '<a href="yourcontorler/' . urlencode('www.google.com?test=test&test2=test2') ">test</a>';
```

In that way, there is no conflicts between google vars and yours.

See [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) manual for details.

Comment: Well i will not be able to urlencode, because user will be adding the second url and i am not able to get the second url into my index method